# Oracle sqlload : split a source field in several columns?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

i have a source file i want to load through sqlload in my Oracle 10g

the problem is one of the source field can be larger than 4000 character. Is it possible to tell oracle to split a source field in several columns ?
let's say one column would have 4000 first character and the second one the 4000 next

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd load it into a CLOB and then do the splitting (if necessary) using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR over on the database side. But is there a critical business reason to get it into multiple varchar2 columns, or could it just stay in the CLOB?

Comment: It could stay in a CLOB as long as Business Objects can handle it after.. My main concern was that i already have 10 varchar(1024) empty fields and i would have preferred using them instead of adding a CLOB